# converting a bz2 xml file to json in python

Tags: python, json, xml

I have downloaded a file from `planet.openstreetmap.org` which is a `.xml.bz2` file. I cannot extract it onto my hard drive because of how big it is (73GB compressed).

I know that I can read the file in python using the `bz2` module, but what's the best way to convert it from XML to JSON?

It just needs to be able to read from the bz2 file a little bit at a time and then write the JSON to a new file.

I have tried looking at `xmljson`, but it doesn't seem to be able to stream